# Need help sed, awk or other tool that can manupulate text files

Tags: python, sed, awk, text-editing

I have a text file Test.m3u that contains file names:

```
FileName1.mp4
FileName2.mp4
FileName3.mp4
```

I need to make a playlist in the following form:

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:FileName1
PATH/FileName1.mp4
#EXTINF:FileName2
PATH/FileName2.mp4
#EXTINF:FileName3
PATH/FileName3.mp4
```

The command:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/PATH:/' test.m3u
```

will add Path to each line but how can I put the line #EXTINF:FileNameX above each line ?

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -i -ne '/(.*)\.mp4/;print "#EXTINF:$1\nPATH/$_"' -- file
```

You can also include

```
BEGIN { print "#EXTM3U\n\n" }
```

to get the header in the output.

- `-i` changes the file(s) "in place"
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- parentheses `()` create a capture group, what matches the first capture group populates `$1` (similar to `\1` in sed)
- `\.`, like in sed, matches the literal dot
- [print](http://p3rl.org/print) just outputs its arguments
- `$_` under `-n` is the contents of the current line

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked. I am on Mac and my sed seems not to go with \n but Perl has no issues. The only problem I don't quite understand the syntax you gave. Could you recommend some read on this subject? Pearl for little ones, or something like that? :)

Comment: @PinPiguin: Added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

this command worked for me:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/#EXTINF:\1\nPATH\/\1.\2/' test.m3u                                                
#EXTINF:FileName1
PATH/FileName1.mp4
#EXTINF:FileName2
PATH/FileName2.mp4
#EXTINF:FileName3
PATH/FileName3.mp4
```

explanation:

`.*` - this matches anything

`\(.*\)` - this matches anything and can be reused (by \1  and the next one  with \2)

`\.` - this matches the actual dot character (which separates basename from extension in this case)

`\n` - this inserts new line